# No WiFi and Neworking connection on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, network-manager, ethernet

I can achieve the connection to any wifi or wired red, but when I tried in the browser Chrome or Firefox the page doesn't load. It was working perfectly, but I don't know why this error come. The same wifi or wired red works in other computer.

I try restart the network service, clear DNS cache, but nothing works me.
When I execute `iwconfig`

[image]

Not sure if the image helps. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem using:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge resolvconf && sudo apt-get install --reinstall resolvconf
```